# how to add a active class in jquery diagonal image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Diagonal-Slider](http://jquer.in/best-jquery-plugins-for-beautiful-sliders-2013/diagonal-slider/)

I have worked on this plugin but the problem is when I load the on focus the images are in normal state. My problem is how to put a active image by default when loading and hovering.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fire a mouseover event programmatically to select a active image on page load. I use nth chield selecter to fire event on 2 slide you can use 1,3 or anything you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery_content').createDiagonalSlider();


   setTimeout(function(){
   $('.gallery_content .gallery_item:nth-child(2)').mouseover();
   },10);

   });
```

Here is working fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/1tu061u9/

For the functionality that you desired

> make image active until next image is not hovered

You need to replace this code inside DiagonalSlider.js at line no 45.

```
slider.find('.gallery_item').hover(function(){
        var item = $(this);

            if (timeout){
                clearTimeout(timeout);    
            }

            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                zoomIn(item, function(){ }); 
            }, 10);

    }, function(){

    });
```

Here is new working fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ytzg32w6/2/

Comment: Its working But when i remove the mouse it automatically get back to normal state. Until i hover another image previous image should be active(like when am scrolling page down also the image should be active.)

Comment: So you want to make image active until next image is not hovered ?

Comment: Exactly, i  need that only

Comment: I check that plugin but i am not able to find any configuration option to do that. But after take a deeper look in plugin code i am able to find a solution by changing that plugin file. I update my answer for that change in DiagonalSliser.js

Comment: for my requirement am accept, but am trying to place the text on images its not possible to me?